# Relationship through intermediate class with Room

Tags: android, relationship, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm testing Room through an application handling books and authors.

I created a model composed from 3 standard entities (Book, Author, Category) and two relation entities (CategoryForBook, AuthorOfBook) described below

```
@Entity(tableName = "books")
data class Book(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo val publicationYear: Int? = null,
    @ColumnInfo val publisher: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo val coverUrl: String? = null
)

@Entity(tableName = "authors")
data class Author(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo val firstName: String,
    @ColumnInfo val lastName: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo val birthDate: Date?,
    @ColumnInfo val nationality: String?,
    @ColumnInfo val biography: String?,
    @ColumnInfo val pictureUrl: String?
)

@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo val name: String
)

@Entity(
    tableName = "author_of_book", primaryKeys = ["authorId", "bookId"], foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = Author::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("authorId")),
        ForeignKey(entity = Book::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("bookId"))
    ]
)
data class AuthorOfBook(
    @ColumnInfo val authorId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo val bookId: Int
)

@Entity(
    tableName = "categories_for_books", primaryKeys = ["categoryId", "bookId"], foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = Category::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("categoryId")),
        ForeignKey(entity = Book::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("bookId"))
    ]
)
data class CategoryForBook(
    @ColumnInfo val categoryId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo val bookId: Int
)
```

Since a book can be written by several authors and have several categories, I need a many-to-many relationship, hence the relation entities.

Now, I would like to retrieve all the information about a book but since there is this intermediate table (CategoryForBook & AuthorOfBook), I don't know how to write my class FullBookInfo.

Is there a way to create a relationship through another class or have I to use a relation to my intermediate table before reaching the table of interest (Author & Category) ?

Comment: room does support Joins

Comment: Yeah, I know but for testing purpose (and because it's more elegant and easy to understand) I would like to use relations

Comment: You're making very complex approach on easy thing, This thing can be achieved easily via several joins and a referencing table that holds relationship via foreign key.

Comment: I'm just asking a question. SQL joins are great but need to be processed to represent the data as I want it to be. The purpose of Room and ORMs is to avoid as much as possible writing SQL queries. The relation annotation provide that for one-to-one or one-to-many. I just wanted to know if a many-to-many solution existed other than intermediate object